# Yosemite and coreaudio outbound traffic

Tags: macos, audio

Ever since upgrading to Yosemite my Mac Mini is filling our network firewall syslog every minute with a UDP denial to a private address  (10.61.0.119) outside our network.

I made sure that updates were done, signed out of face time and messenger. Checked to see if it was browser related (Chrome) but even when Chrome is closed we still get the hit.

I installed Little Snitch and discovered that it is the coreaudiod trying to get to 10.61.0.119. I can't figure out how to stop it.

Also, this is in my syslog numerous times:

```
coreaudio:2014-10-23 8:23, 790579 A< (AsyncConnection) ### Connect 1 to 10.61.0.119 failed: 64/0X60 EHOSTDOWN
```

Mac mini, OS X Yosemite (10.10)

Comment: I have no clue on the actual answer, but 10.61.x.x is a private address space, like 192.168.x.x

Comment: Coreaudio is the process for dealing with sound on the computer. If it's accessing something on the local network, maybe it's related to Airplay?